# Can (ringer) volume only be locked by hacks/apps or is there a easy way?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, ringtone, volume-control, buttons

I tried several apps to lock the volume button, because when touching them acidentally this always changes my ringer volume. This seems to be default function of volume button - change the ringer volume (how does this make sense? media volume would be better)

Those mentioned apps offer locking of media, ringer, notification ... volume. Some don't work at all (maybe phone specific problem, xperia arc 2.3.4 rooted). One app actually has a working volume locking "function", [RingGuard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsaid=com.x475aws.android.ringguard&feature=search_result), but a very ugly hack. If the volume gets changed acidentally, a popup shows up and asks you to keep this setting, if not, volume is set to former ringer volume, the locked one. It works, but this is very ugly solution and also if I set the phone to vibration mode, this app also wants confirmation. Ugly.

I'm really wondering, is there no "clean" way to simply lock the ringer volume on my phone without a ugly additional app, maybe by system settings. Even my old J2ME phone could do this?

Comment: The volume rocker changes the volume of the currentaudio source. If there isn't it changes the ringtone's. I think it makes perfect sense.